# Kotlin Google Maps doesnt Start

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

```
lass MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        val permissionx= arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionx,0)

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

ı set there the permıssıon code because i want to check if program goes there and the program never goes there and want permıssion ı tried it with Toast too but program never open this

Xml of main activity for map fragment

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="259dp"
            tools:context="com.example.siparis.MapsActivity" />
```

I entered key Correctly i m sure.

Here is my manifest for the program.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.siparis">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Only error in Logcat is that :

> 2020-03-06 16:52:50.323 20804-20804/? E/example.sipari: Unknown bits
>   set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: any exception??

Comment: no exception. let me edit with logcat

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

`Allows an app to access location in the background. If you're requesting this permission, you must also request either ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Requesting this permission by itself doesn't give you location access.`

I think you are missing permissions. Please also request before using.

Comment: i get both permıssıon already And the program will not run in background.

Comment: Please update your question then, because it currently only requests ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Comment: Please note depending on android version declaring in manifest is not enough.

Comment: ı Try to Toast in onmapcreate it doesnt even show the Toast. Or it doesnt even check permıssıon even i code it in the oncreatemap

Answer (score 0):

You should call `mMap.onResume()` inside `onMapReady()`

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))

    //map is the mapview in the layout
    (map as SupportMapFragment).onResume() //this line is very necessary
}
```

Comment: there is no interface mMap.onResume()

Comment: No there is no mMap.onResume()

Comment: @OğuzKurukaya Cast your map to a `SupportMapFragment` if you are using a `fragment` and not a `MapView` in your layout.

Comment: i use as SupportMapFragment in all code did ı miss somewhere